How does the concept of "steepness" extend to derivatives beyond the first for an $f(x,y)$?
If one has a smooth function $z = f(x,y)$ in a 3-dimensional space, one could define the slope at a given point as the steepest slope at that point, with the option to choose any angle in the $xy$ plane at that point. For example, if
$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$
then the slopes defined by $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$ and $f_y=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y$ are different, but they can be combined using the Pythagorean theorem to determine the magnitude of the most extreme slope along the surface at that point $\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which makes sense for this function, since it's radially symmetric.
I noticed, then, for any derivative (using $x_1$ instead of $x$, $x_2$ instead of $y$, etc.), that the sum of the squares of all derivatives of that order is invariant when a function like $f(x,y)=xy$ is rotated about the z axis with  $x' = x\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta}$ and $y'=x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}$ at the new transformed coordinates (apologies if the notation is off):
$$\sum_{\bigcup\{i_1,i_2,...,i_n|i_k \in \{1,2\}\}  } f^2_{x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_k}} $$
For the 2nd derivative, $f^2_{xx} + 2f^2_{xy} + f^2_{yy}$ appears to be constant, for the 3rd derivative, $f^2_{xxx} + 3f^2_{xxy} + 3f^2_{xyy} + f^2_{yyy}$, and so on.
I imagine that the analogs to "steepness" might be the square roots of these sums, but the closest thing to this concept that I have seen is curvature, which requires both first and second derivatives to define and has multiple ways of measuring it in 3-dimensional space.
My questions about this are

Are my observations and assumptions accurate?

Is there a good way to visualize (conceptually) these sums of squares when including the mixed partial derivatives (e.g., vectors in a $2^n$-dimensional space)?

Is there a name for what I am describing, or any particularly useful properties of it?



Read about the gradient on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient
